# r data wrangling multiply and by group

Tags: r

I am aiming to estimate a scalar value based on the formula:

```
Z_t11(Z_t12 + Z_t13 + Z_t14) + Z_t12(Z_t13 + Z_t14) + Z_t13(Z_t14) +
Z_t21(Z_t22 + Z_t23 + Z_t24 + Z_t25) + Z_t22(Z_t23 + Z_t24 + Z_t25) + Z_t23(Z_t24 + Z_t25) +  Z_t24(Z_t25)
```

**Z_t11** is `Z` value at `Time 1` for `ID 1` is `-1.5`

**Z_t13** is `Z` value at `Time 3` for `ID 1`  is `0.5`

```
 ID    Time   Z
 1     1     -1.5
 1     2     -1.5
 1     3      0.5
 1     4      0.5
 2     1     -0.5
 2     2     -0.5
 2     3     -2.0
 2     4     -1.5
 2     5      1.5
```

How do I caluclate:

```
  -1.5*(-1.5+0.5+0.5) - 1.5*(0.5+0.5) + 0.5*(0.5) +
  -0.5*(-0.5-2.0-1.5+1.5) -0.5*(-2.0-1.5+1.5) -2.0*(-1.5+1.5) -1.5*1.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grouped by 'ID', loop over the `row_number()`, use that as index to extract the 'Z' values that succeeds for each row, get the `sum` and multiply with the corresponding 'Z' value and then take the overall `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   summarise(Z1 = sum(map_dbl(row_number(), 
            ~ Z[.x] * sum(Z[row_number() > .x]))))
```

NOTE: For the last row of each group, it returns 0 because there is no case for `row_number() > n()`

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Time = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), Z = c(-1.5, -1.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
-0.5, -0.5, -2, -1.5, 1.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** For each ID the indicated function gives the required sum and then sum those values calculated for each ID.  No packages are used.

```
with(DF, sum(tapply(Z, ID, function(z) sum(z * (sum(z) - cumsum(z)))))) 
## [1] -0.5
```

**2)**  Another approach is to convert DF to wide form Z and then use string manipulation on the text of the expression shown in the question to convert ( to *( and Z_t11 to Z[1, 1], etc. and then parse and evaluate that against Z.  No packages are used.

```
# next line is expression shown in question
s <- "Z_t11(Z_t12 + Z_t13 + Z_t14) + Z_t12(Z_t13 + Z_t14) + Z_t13(Z_t14) + Z_t21(Z_t22 + Z_t23 + Z_t24 + Z_t25) + Z_t22(Z_t23 + Z_t24 + Z_t25) + Z_t23(Z_t24 + Z_t25) + Z_t24(Z_t25)"

Z <- xtabs(Z ~., DF)
s |>
  gsub(pattern = "\\(", replacement = "*(") |>
  gsub(pattern = "_t(.)(.)", replacement = "[\\1, \\2]") |>
  parse(file = "", n = NULL) |>
  eval()
## [1] -0.5
```

### Note

The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "ID    Time   Z
 1     1     -1.5
 1     2     -1.5
 1     3      0.5
 1     4      0.5
 2     1     -0.5
 2     2     -0.5
 2     3     -2.0
 2     4     -1.5
 2     5      1.5"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Also the numeric expression shown at the end of the question evaluates like this:

```
-1.5*(-1.5+0.5+0.5) - 1.5*(0.5+0.5) + 0.5*(0.5) +
 -0.5*(-0.5-2.0-1.5+1.5) -0.5*(-2.0-1.5+1.5) -2.0*(-1.5+1.5) -1.5*1.5
## [1] -0.5
```